# Java SDK for Facebook Ads API 2.10 missing AdsInsights.getFieldImpressionDevice() method

Tags: facebook-ads-api, facebook-insights, facebook-java-api

Currently using Facebook Ads SDK for Java v2.9 and trying to upgrade to v2.10 or v2.11. However, neither of the newer versions has the method getFieldImpressionDevice on the AdInsights object? I haven't found any change log info that discusses a change or deprecation around this call. Anyone have any insight into this problem?

Also a little confused as to why github :

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-java-ads-sdk/

doesn't have the 2.10 or 2.11 libs only the 2.9 libs even though this link indicates it, eg.,

src/main/java/com/facebook/ads  Ads SDK v2.11 Release   Nov 8, 2017

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

There's a known issue it turns out. Some (or all) of the breakdown fields and methods in the AdsInsights class were left out. It can be worked around using raw json, eg.,

```
JsonObject jo = insight.getRawResponseAsJsonObject();
JsonElement je = jo.get("impression_device");
String device = je.getAsString();
```